# Function App not showing up on list of functions after deployment from gitlab pipeline

Tags: azure, gitlab, azure-functions

I prepared Gitlab pipeline to publish azure function.

```
stages:
  - publish

image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:4-node18-core-tools

.publish:
  stage: publish
  script:
    - npm install @azure/functions
    - az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID --federated-token `cat $AZURE_FEDERATED_TOKEN_FILE` --tenant $AZURE_TENANT_ID
    - cd src/functions
    - |
      echo '{
        "IsEncrypted": false,
        "Values": {
            "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
            "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
        }
      }' > local.settings.json
    - npm run build
    - func azure functionapp publish example-functions-acc
```

Unfortunatelly pipeline working correctly, no errors.
But function App not showing up on list after deployment.

```
$ npm install @azure/functions
added 48 packages, and audited 49 packages in 2s
14 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
found 0 vulnerabilities
$ az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID --federated-token `cat $AZURE_FEDERATED_TOKEN_FILE` --tenant $AZURE_TENANT_ID
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "6246c9fe-79e6-4621-bcc2-xxxx",
    "id": "c606ee86-7f71-4aa3-be45-xxxx",
    "isDefault": true,
    "managedByTenants": [],
    "name": "Example - Acceptance",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "6246c9fe-79e6-4621-bcc2-xxx",
    "user": {
      "name": "d63551ed-959a-4b9d-90ff-xxx",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  }
]
$ cd src/functions
$ echo '{ # collapsed multi-line command
$ npm run build
> exampletaskrunner@1.0.0 build
> tsc
$ func azure functionapp publish example-functions-acc
Getting site publishing info...
Uploading package...
Uploading 534 B []
Upload completed successfully.
Deployment completed successfully.
Syncing triggers...
Functions in example-functions-acc:
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "exampletaskrunner",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "prestart": "npm run clean && npm run build",
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.x",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "main": "dist/src/functions/*.js"
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false
  }
}
```

BlobFunction.ts

```
import { app, InvocationContext } from '@azure/functions';

export async function airlinesCSVBlobTrigger(myBlob: Buffer, context: InvocationContext): Promise<void> {

    const url = 'https://my-acc.example.com/api/airlines';

    const options = {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ token: 'nN4P0aImxxxxxx' })
    }
    
    await fetch(url, options);
    context.log("EXAMPLE-FE blob trigger function processed blob", myBlob.length);
    // context.log("EXAMPLE-FE blob trigger function processed blob \n Blob:", context.bindingData.blobTrigger, "\n Blob Size:", myBlob.length, "Bytes");
}

app.storageBlob('airlinesCSVBlobTrigger', {
    path: 'i5docs/AirlinesMapper.csv',
    connection: 'example_STORAGE',
    handler: airlinesCSVBlobTrigger
});
```

I have existing function, which developer delivered.
When he deploys by IDE VSCode I see on the list.
Problem is with pipeline.
Do you have any ideas?
I am not familiar with TypeScript pipeline.

Comment: can you share your function code, package.json and tsconfig,json file

Comment: I added bodyfunction.ts,package.json,tsconfig.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes in my GitLab `.yml` file and it worked for me.

I have two triggers

```
1.httpTrigger1
2.storageBlobTrigger1
```

- Make sure to add `"AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"` in the Environment variables of Function app.

[image]

This worked for me

**`.gitlab-ci.yml`:**

```yaml
variables:
 Function_name:  "nodegitlab"
 Client_id:  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 Client_secret:  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 tenant_id:  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 
image:  mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:4-node18-core-tools
Deploy-job:
 stage:  deploy
 script: 
 -  az  login  --service-principal  --allow-no-subscriptions  -u  $Client_id  -p  $Client_secret  --tenant  $tenant_id
 -  npm  install
 -  npm  run  clean
 -  npm  run  build
 -  func  azure  functionapp  publish  $Function_name  --typescript
```

**`package.json`**

```json
{
  "name": "typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "prestart": "npm run clean && npm run build",
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.x",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "main": "dist/src/functions/*.js"
}
```

**`tsconfig.json`:**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false
  }
}
```

**`httpTrigger1.ts`:**

```js
import { app, HttpRequest, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext } from "@azure/functions";

export async function httpTrigger1(request: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
    context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

    const name = request.query.get('name') || await request.text() || 'world';

    return { body: `Hello, ${name}!` };
};

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: httpTrigger1
});
```

**`storageBlobTrigger1.ts`:**

```js
import { app, InvocationContext } from "@azure/functions";

export async function storageBlobTrigger1(blob: Buffer, context: InvocationContext): Promise<void> {
    context.log(`Storage blob function processed blob "${context.triggerMetadata.name}" with size ${blob.length} bytes`);
}

app.storageBlob('storageBlobTrigger1', {
    path: 'nodetest/{name}',
    connection: 'AzureWebJobsStorage',
    handler: storageBlobTrigger1
});
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

```
$ az login --service-principal --allow-no-subscriptions -u $Client_id -p $Client_secret --tenant $tenant_id
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "isDefault": true,
    "managedByTenants": [
      {
        "tenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    ],
    "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "state": "Enabled",
    "tenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "user": {
      "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  }
]
$ npm install
added 48 packages, and audited 49 packages in 2s
14 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
found 0 vulnerabilities
$ npm run clean
> typescript@1.0.0 clean
> rimraf dist
$ npm run build
> typescript@1.0.0 build
> tsc
$ func azure functionapp publish $Function_name --typescript
Getting site publishing info...
Creating archive for current directory...
Uploading 13.82 MB []
Deployment completed successfully.
Syncing triggers...
Functions in nodegitlab:
    httpTrigger1 - [httpTrigger]
        Invoke url: https://nodegitlab.azurewebsites.net/api/httptrigger1
    storageBlobTrigger1 - [blobTrigger]
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much.
I removed section
```    - cd src/functions
    - |
      echo '{
        "IsEncrypted": false,
        "Values": {
            "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
            "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
        }
      }' > local.settings.json
```
and working.
I am still wondering why.